# vim: difference between :n and :bn

Tags: vim

If I started vim with multiple files like so `vim *.java`, I can cycle through opened files using either `:n` or `:bn` (and other related commands).

But if I start with only one file and load other files using `:split` (and later close the split window), I can cycle the buffers using `:bn` but not `:n`.

What is the difference between these two situations? If I do :buffers in both cases, there is no difference whatsoever in the buffer list. It might seem like I am asking unnecessary question but I would like to understand if there is any gotchas lurking under the hood. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `:bn` et al. always cycle through all buffers, `:n` et al depend on how the buffers were created.

**Explanation**:

`:n` is short for `:next` which moves in the argument list (which you can view by doing `:args`)

`:bn` is short for `:bnext` which moves in the buffer list

Opening a file with `:sp foo` does not alter the argument list, but adds a buffer, and hence does not change the behaviour of`:n`, but does affect `:bn`.

On the other hand, if you open a new file with `:n foo`, that replaces the argument list (also changing the behaviour of `:n` et al, but not that of `:bn` et al.) .

An example session:

```
$ vim /tmp/foo /tmp/bar

:args
[foo] bar

:buffers
  1 %a   "foo"                          line 1
  2      "bar"                          line 0
```

Here, the buffer and argument lists match

```
:sp /tmp/sna

:args
[foo] bar

:buffers
  1 #a   "foo"                          line 0
  2      "bar"                          line 0
  3 %a   "sna"                          line 1
```

Now, there is a new buffer, but the argument list is the same

```
:n /tmp/test /tmp/baz

:args
[test] baz

:buffers
  1  a   "foo"                          line 0 
  2      "bar"                          line 0 
  3 #    "sna"                          line 1 
  4 %a   "test"                         line 1 
  5      "baz"                          line 0
```

And now the argument list was replaced, and the buffer list extended.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks :)

Comment: [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Meet the arglist](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/meet-the-arglist/)

Answer (score 6):

`:bnext` loads the next *buffer* from the *buffer list* in the current window.

`:next` loads the next *file* from the *argument list* in the current window.

In practice, every file in the argument list is loaded into a buffer and thus added to the buffer list but, while changes to the argument list *may* have some impact on the buffer list, changes to the buffer list *never* have any impact on the argument list. This means that the two lists *can* be equivalent but that there's no guarantee at all about that.

`:n` *may* load the next buffer from the buffer list and `:bn` *may* load the next file in the argument list but this shouldn't be considered as anything other than a side effect.

Use `:bn` and friends when you actually work with buffers and `:n` and friends when you work with the argument list.